# How to get the details of triads in r/python?

Tags: python, r, networkx, igraph, sna

I am currently using `igraph` to get the traid census of a given directed graph using`triad_census(g)`. This returns the count of triads in each of the 16 classes.

e.g., `16  3  0 10  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0`

However, I would like to know more details of the triads than these summary statistics.

i.e. given that the network has 16 of `003`, what they are? given that the network has 3 `012`, what they are?

**Example:** The 3 traids of `012` are `(john -> emi, jenne)`, `(cena -> ally, john)`, `(emi -> peter, david)`

Is there a way of doing this in r or python?

**MWE**

Graph data: http://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=sites&srcid=ZGVmYXVsdGRvbWFpbnxkYWlzaGl6dWthfGd4OmFmZTI0NjhlMjQ0ZDQ5MQ

Code:

```
library(igraph)
#import the sample_dw_adj.csv file:
dat=read.csv(file.choose(),header=TRUE,row.names=1,check.names=FALSE) # read .csv file
m=as.matrix(dat)
net=graph.adjacency(m,mode="directed",weighted=TRUE,diag=FALSE)
plot.igraph(net,vertex.label=V(net)$name,layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold, vertex.label.color="black",edge.color="black",edge.width=E(net)$weight/3, edge.arrow.size=1.5)
```

So, my actual graph would look like as follows.
[image]

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example? You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) if you need any tips on how to do that.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Sure, I will update the question. I saw your comment just now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a builtin method to accomplish what you want with Networkx. However, you can manually go through each triad and define which class it belongs to:

```
from itertools import combinations

triad_class = {}
for nodes in combinations(G.nodes, 3):
    triad_class[nodes] = [k for k, v in nx.triads.triadic_census(G.subgraph(nodes)).items() if v][0]
```

If you'd rather have a dictionary with the classes as the keys, you can try something like this:

```
from itertools import combinations

triad_class = {}
for nodes in combinations(G.nodes, 3):
    tc = [k for k, v in nx.triads.triadic_census(G.subgraph(nodes)).items() if v][0]
    triad_class.setdefault(tc, []).append(nodes)
```

Comment: Hi, I checked your code, and that worked. Thank you once again :)

Comment: Please let me know if you know an answer for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54730863/how-to-get-triad-census-in-undirected-graph-using-networkx-in-python Thank you :)